# Powershell script will not overwrite the file, but it will create a new file and overwrtite it

Tags: powershell

I am using this Powershell script to replace the content of a file:

```
$lines = Get-Content -Path D:\file.txt -Encoding UTF8 -Raw
$option = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline 

$pattern1 = [regex]::new("(\[\.dfn \.term])#(.*?)#", $option)
$lines = $pattern1.Replace($lines, '$1_$2_')

$pattern2 = [regex]::new("(\[what you want])#(.*?)#", $option)
$lines = $pattern2.Replace($lines, '$1*$2*')
```

It is supposed to find some content in the file and overwrite the file. But it will not overwrite.

However, if I use the script like this:

```
$lines = Get-Content -Path D:\file.txt -Encoding UTF8 -Raw
$option = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline 

$pattern1 = [regex]::new("(\[\.dfn \.term])#(.*?)#", $option)
$lines = $pattern1.Replace($lines, '$1_$2_')

$pattern2 = [regex]::new("(\[what you want])#(.*?)#", $option)
$lines = $pattern2.Replace($lines, '$1*$2*')

$lines | Set-Content -Path D:\result.txt -Encoding UTF8
```

The script will create a new file and write the result into it. And it will even overwrite result.txt every time the script is run. But if I explicitly say that I want to write the result to file.txt, it will not do that.

How to make the script overwrite the existing file?

My main tests were in Powershell version 5.1.19041.610

No explicit errors in the PS window and no changes to the file. But the file is replaced if I add `$lines | Set-Content -Path D:\result.txt -Encoding UTF8 -Force`

I also tested it on Powershell version 7.1.3.0.

No explicit errors in the PS window and no changes to the file. But the file is replaced if I add `$lines | Set-Content -Path D:\result.txt -Encoding UTF8` without Force.

[image: powershells]

Comment: Which error message do you get if you execute `...| Set-Content -Path D:\file.txt ...`

Comment: i have no problem to open and rewrite in same file..what is your version of Powershell? if no erro i think -force could resolve some problem  (if your version of PS is old)

Comment: @stackprotector I get no error messages. The script just runs.

Comment: @VladimirMarkiev So, `...| Set-Content -Path D:\file.txt ... ` just does not overwrite `file.txt` that you previously read in? And does not throw any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally, Get-content opens, reads and closes the file

you could try

```
$lines | Set-Content -Path D:\result.txt -Encoding UTF8 -Force
```

> -Force
> Override restrictions that prevent the command from succeeding. Force will replace
> the contents of a file, even if the file is read-only, but will not override
> security permissions. Without this parameter, read-only files are not changed.